# Maps between Euclidian spaces that preserve lines are affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, real-numbers, projective-space, affine-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function and $n\geq 2$ such that the image of every line of the form $$x+tv $$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $v\in B(0,1)$ is still a line.

Can we say that $f$ is an affine map?

Comment: This seems to fail for $n=1$

Comment: Central projections preserve lines but are not affine.

Comment: @bubba, what do you mean with central projections?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, true, I edit with $n\geq 2$

Comment: This thing. It occurs in perspective projections in computer graphics.  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/central-projection

Comment: I expect these mappings have different names in projective geometry, but I don’t know much about that subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to assume that $f$ is a bijection then you can apply the fundamental theorem of projective geometry to conclude that what you want is true. Here is a [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#Fundamental_theorem_of_projective_geometry), and here is a [mathoverflow link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191817/who-first-proved-the-fundamental-theorem-of-projective-geometry).

The way that theorem is applied is to first conclude that $f$ is a line-preserving  bijection of $\mathbb RP^n = \mathbb R^n \cup \{\infty\}$. The fundamental theorem then lets you conclude that $f$ is projective transformation. Since $f$ fixes infinity, it follows that $f$ is an affine map.